# ohshopify.php, undefined session vars & other undefined vars

Tags: php, session, shopify

I'm having trouble getting the desired result from the [ohShopify.php](https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php#readme) PHP JSON client.

Please forgive me as I am quite new to php et al, but will try to explain my problem as clearly as possible.

I'm not sure if this relevant information, but I'm using WAMP with PHP 5.3.13 on Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Here's my index.php

```
require 'shopify.php';
$api_key    = '---';
$secret = '---';
$scope      = read_products;

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 

    $shopifyClient = new ShopifyClient($_GET['shop'], "", $api_key, $secret);
    session_unset();


    $_SESSION['token'] = $shopifyClient->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    if ($_SESSION['token'] != '')
        $_SESSION['shop'] = $_GET['shop'];

    header("Location: store.php");
    exit;   

} else {    

    $shop = '---.shopify.com';
    $shopifyClient = new ShopifyClient($shop, "", $api_key, $secret);

    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") { $pageURL .= "s"; }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    header("Location: " . $shopifyClient->getAuthorizeUrl($scope, $pageURL));
    exit;
}
```

Which when successful sets the location to my store.php:

```
require 'shopify.php';

$sc = new ShopifyClient($_SESSION['shop'], $_SESSION['token'], $api_key, $secret);

try
{
    // Get all products
    $products = $sc->call('GET', '/admin/products.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));




}
catch (ShopifyApiException $e)
{
    /* 
     $e->getMethod() -> http method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
     $e->getPath() -> path of failing request
     $e->getResponseHeaders() -> actually response headers from failing request
     $e->getResponse() -> curl response object
     $e->getParams() -> optional data that may have been passed that caused the failure

    */
}
catch (ShopifyCurlException $e)
{
    // $e->getMessage() returns value of curl_errno() and $e->getCode() returns value of curl_ error()
}
```

This is where I'm getting errors. None of the variables are set. $_SESSION, $api_key and $secret are all coming back "undefined".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bllWS.gif)

I'm guessing that I'm missing something but have been looking for hours and can't figure it out. How can $_SESSION be undefined seeing as it's a "superglobal" variable.

If there's any more information I can provide, let me know. Thanks in advance.